# iPhone: how to let the music play for an application using OpenAL?

Tags: iphone, openal

I'm writing an iPhone app that uses OpenAL.  When the application starts, the music playing in background stops.

The music actually stops playing when I initialize the OpenAL library.

My question is, is there any way to use OpenAL while letting the background music play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the Audio Session Category to kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound instead of kAudioSessionCategory_SoloAmbientSound which is the default.

You can find out more about it in the [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Here's a [link](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4-SW1) to the relevant part of the documentation.